# Json : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, entity

This Code;

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string jSon = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    string result = LETSGO.BUSINESS.Process.ApiProcesRequest(jSon);        
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(result);
}
```

Error : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.

How do I fix error ?

This function send;

```
public static string ApiProcesRequest(string request)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        try
        {
            var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(request);
            switch (req.RequestType)
            {
                #region 1002 - Kullanıcı şifre hatırlatma
                case "1002":
                    result = UserProcess.PasswordReminder(request);
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
                    break;
                #endregion } } }
```

Comment: You're missing the most important piece - what are you parsing into your function?

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Also, can you show us the JSON that it's trying to parse (i.e. the data that's read from the input stream)?

Answer (score 2):

```
string jSon = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Here you might got the string like `s.Path`, it can not be deserialize due to it's not a well-formed json object.

Comment: @Ekskalibbur please use debug , to see the content of 'jSon', this string must contains something like 's.Path', and this is not a json object!

Comment: Screenshot;
{"Code":"Err","Message":"Hata! Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","Value":null,"UserId":0}


Help me !

Comment: @Ekskalibbur all values should be wrapped with double quotes, the "null" and "0" are not. Add the quotes and it might work.